# Choose Android.R.layout when setup GridView in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview, android-adapter

[image]

I am currently working on a grid view.

Since the grid view item is only a textview, I have not create a custom layout.

But when I tried to use simple_list_item_1, I found that the item click area is just the size of the text, not the whole item.

So I changed to simple_list_item_single_choice, the click area is whole item but the text is not at the center of the view

Therefore, I wonder what should I choose for the layout? 
1. Text center in the view
2. Clickable the whole item instead of only the text view

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why not create a custom layout ?

Comment: thats because all I need is only a text view,  it is the last resort if all default layout are not fit

Comment: You are aware that using a custom layout would have taken less time than the time you used search the right layout or write the question ? If you are a beginner and need help to get the proper layout, say it.

Comment: Thanks for you help. It would be nice if there is a recommend layout. If there isn't one.  I am going to complete it by custom layout then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as a layout! ;D

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

These are the differences..

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
```